# How to compile and apply SELinux policy

Tags: fedora, selinux

I'm student. I want to use the policy compiled from the source code.
After compiling the policy, the following error statement is displayed.
Please tell me how to compile and apply SELinux policy.

```
systemd[1]: Unable to fix SELinux security context of /run/systemd/journal/dev-log: Permission denied
systemd[1]: Unable to fix SELinux security context of /run/systemd/journal/socket: Permission denied
:
systemd-journald[529]: Faild to open /run/systemd/journal/kernelseqnum, ignoring: Permission denied
:

audit: backlog limit exceeded
audit: backlog limit exceeded
audit: backlog limit exceeded
audit: backlog limit exceeded
audit: backlog limit exceeded
:
```

The procedure I did is shown below.

```
Fedora 26 (linux4.11.8-300)
1)  yumdownloader --source selinux-policy
2)  rpm -ivh selinux-policy-3.13.1-260.8.fc26.src.rpm
3)  rpmbuild -bi ~/rpmbuild/SPEC/selinux-policy.spec --define "BUILD_STRICT 0" --define "BUILD_MLS 0"
4)  cd ~/rpmbuild/BUILD/selinux-3.13.1/
5)  vi build.conf
 ----
 TYPE = mcs
 NAME = test
 DISTRO = redhat
 UNK_PERMS = allow
 DIRECT_INITRC = y
 MONOLITHIC = n
 UBAC = n
 CUSTOM_BUILDOPT =
 MLS_SENS = 16
 MLS_CATS = 1024
 MCS_CATS = 1024
 QUIET = n
 ----
6)  make install-src
7)  cd /etc/selinux/test/src/policy
8)  make load
9)  touch /.autorelabel
10) edit /etc/selinux/config file
11) reboot
12) "audit:backlog limit exceeded" continues to be outputted
```

I increased the buffer size but it did not change.

```
/etc/audit/audit.rules
# Set buffer size
-b 8192
```

Comment: Run as root. use sudo.

Comment: The above is done with root authority.

Answer (score 1):

For what I can see here you are actually not compiling and installing the policy.

To compile the policy, I would do:

1. yumdownloader --source selinux-policy
2. rpm -ivh selinux-policy-3.13.1-260.8.fc26.src.rpm
3. rpmbuild **-bp** ~/rpmbuild/SPEC/selinux-policy.spec --define "BUILD_STRICT 0" --define "BUILD_MLS 0" #this patch the code with fedora patches
4. cd ~/rpmbuild/BUILD/selinux-3.13.1/
5. vi build.conf

   `TYPE = mcs
   NAME = test
   DISTRO = redhat
   UNK_PERMS = allow
   DIRECT_INITRC = y
   MONOLITHIC = n
   UBAC = n
   CUSTOM_BUILDOPT =
   MLS_SENS = 16
   MLS_CATS = 1024
   MCS_CATS = 1024
   QUIET = n`
6. **make config**
7. **make**
8. **make install install-headers**
9. make load
10. touch /.autorelabel
11. edit /etc/selinux/config file
12. reboot